# Running South migrations for all apps

Tags: python, django, django-models, migration, django-south

I've just begun using South and am still in the process of figuring it out. Let's say I have the initial migration script of a model. Then i go add a column to the model and create a migration script for it. I then add another column to another model and create another migration script for it. I'm creating the migration script by running `./manage.py schemamigration myappname --auto`.

Let's say I have a server on which my project is deployed but it was based on the initial schema of the application but now it lags behind the repository by two migrations. I can bring it up to date by running `./manage.py migrate myappname`. This would bring that app's models up to date by running the the new migrations if I'm correct but I would explicitly have to specify the app.

Does South allow you run all pending migrations for all apps in a Django project? If so how? I haven't able to find any thing in the docs about this.

Thanks a ton everyone.

Comment: Leopd is right. Check out the command reference in the docs: http://south.aeracode.org/docs/commands.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To bring all apps up to date on all their migrations, run:

```
./manage.py migrate
```

Simple.  :)

Comment: I remember having to add the --all parameter but could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
./manage.py syncdb --migrate
```

to *migrate* all applications which use south and *sync* the applications which do not.